# Communication between raspberry pi and android

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi, adb

I want to connect a linux machine(eventually a raspberry pi) and android phone using usb to microusb. Is it possible to assign IPs and do client server programming?

Comment: Yes - one option is to enable tethering which seems to create a local network.  Another would be to port adb to the pi and use port or unix socket forwards.